# Writing in Firestore is taking too much

Tags: ruby, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a notification system and I'm using Google Cloud Firestore to store the notifications messages. the Idea was to have an schema as following. A collection notifications with documents that represent the role of the "user" a nested collection with the Id's of that users and inside of the Id's document a collection with the notifications for that users ex: notification->customer->88 has a collection of messages for the customer 88, the messages Id's are random created by Firestore.

In some case I'm sending the message to 800 users so I'm doing in bach by 500 (BATCH_LIMIT) that it's the limit to writes in firestore in a request. For that I'm using this code.

```rb
  def self.save(entities, message)
    entities.each_slice(BATCH_LIMIT) do |entities_chunk|
      firestore.batch do |batch|
        entities_chunk.each do |entity|
          collection_reference = firestore.col(BASE_COLLECTION).doc(entity.account_type).col(entity.account_id).doc
          batch.set(collection_reference, message)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This operation takes up to 180 second to complete (800 writes aprox) in Google Cloud Firestore. Is this normal ? This does not scale. There is another way to do it?

Comment: if there is no error in your code then this is not normal. And firebase stores data pretty quickly. Did you tries batch write?

Comment: @KevinRED Batch writes are typically not substantially faster than sending the same as individual writes.

Comment: is there any ref for that?

Comment: See the note at the bottom of this section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes. If you don't need atomicity, use parallelized individual writes.